# Running php scripts within echo

Tags: php, html, php-7

We're working on CDN website that can load more than just images, specially we want to host code and allow it to be rendered with or without php and other backends directly; however there is one problem.

In PHP, when we echo the contents of a user submission that contains php code in it of it's self, it prints it out instead of doing whats inside, can anyone think of way we could make the PHP run? We can't really think of anything.

Perhaps we should generate a temporary file and put the content in there then use the `require` function? I'm not sure really. Any help would be great.

For instance, here is some demo content to work with while answering the question.

**User Submission to CDN**

```
<h1>My Site! :)</h1>
<p>Good morning,</p>
<p><?php
echo $_COOKIE['name'];
?></p>
```

**The Loading Process**

```
(database code)
$usercontent = $row['sourcecode'];

if($requestedraw) {
   header("content-type: text/json");
   if($runphpinside) {
      (Perhaps a "runphpfirst" function for parsing it?)
      echo runphpfirst($usercontent);
   } else {
      echo $usercontent;
   }
} else {
   header("content-type: text/html");
   echo runphpfirst($usercontent);
}
```

**Current Result - From Browser**

```
<h1>My Site! :)</h1>
<p>Good morning,</p>
<p><?php
echo $_COOKIE['name'];
?></p>
```

**Expected Result - From Browser**

```
<h1>My Site! :)</h1>
<p>Good morning,</p>
<p>ExampleUsername</p>
```

~ N.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for [`eval()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php).  Of course it's worth pointing out for future readers that there are obvious security risks in executing user-submitted code.

Comment: CDNs cache static content. If you're running user-provided code it's: 1, Not a CDN anymore. 2. A gigantic security hole. If your users want to do something like this then have them provide a backend URL that will run whatever code they want and provide the response to the CDN including the necessary caching headers. This is basically how all pull-through CDNs work.

Comment: Use require_once - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php

Comment: @Sammitch @David; thanks for your input. Perhaps your right, I'll make sure there are restrictions in place for customer content. I'm thinking that using the eval() method in combination with a virtual playground for the customer may be the best decision. Our CDN is not just for static content as it hooks into our other services and provides other changeable options including filters (imgs only), minification/scalling, etc. the code I provided was just an example but I understand your prospective.